# Get Next Work Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have this function which should return the next work date:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BusDaysDateAdd] 
(
   @FromDate datetime,
   @DaysToAdd int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Result datetime

   SET @Result = DATEADD(day, (@DaysToAdd % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) + (@DaysToAdd % 5)) % 7)
                                                 WHEN 0 THEN 2
                                                 WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                 ELSE 0 END, DATEADD(week, (@DaysToAdd / 5), @FromDate))

   RETURN @Result
END

    Set DATEFIRST 1

Select

    'Today'
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),1))
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),2))
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),3))
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),4))
    ,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),5))
    ,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),3)
    ,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),4)
    ,dbo.BusDaysDateAdd(getdate(),5)
```

The problem is that it returns Monday if want to add 4 days but it should return Tuesday.

Can anyone point out where the problem is my code?

Comment: Can you please update with Expected output (input and output date)?

Comment: Can u check the function , u r mistake is 3+2 = 5 and 4+1 = 5 which makes the day as Monday in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying ur function like this

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BusDaysDateAdd] 
(
   @FromDate datetime,
   @DaysToAdd int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Result datetime

   SET @Result = DATEADD(day, (@DaysToAdd % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) + (@DaysToAdd % 5)) % 7)
                                                 WHEN 0 THEN 2
                                                 WHEN 1 THEN 2
                                                 ELSE 0 END, DATEADD(week, (@DaysToAdd / 5), @FromDate))

   RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: You might want to explain what you changed and why you believe that fixes the problem, because it took me a while to spot what you did.

Comment: Looks like he changed: WHEN 1 THEN 1 to WHEN 1 THEN 2 from the first query.

Comment: This is close, but if you start on a weekend and add 2 business days, it should return tuesday but this returns monday. This query works if you start on a business day though.

Comment: I am still testing this. Maybe it would work with a loop

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SET @Result = DATEADD(day, 
                      @DaysToAdd + 
                        CASE DATEPART(weekday, DATEADD(day, @DaysToAdd,@fromdate))
                             WHEN 6 THEN 2
                             WHEN 7 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0 END, 
                      @FromDate)
```

Comment: You can't blindly use the output of `DATEPART(weekday, ...)`, because it's culture-dependent.  That's what the `@@DATEFIRST` was being used for; to adjust so that the output was consistent across all cultures.

Comment: Hi, Could you please clarify the changes? It works now but what was the change?

Comment: I'm checking if the date (@fromdate + @DaysToAdd) is on a Saturday or Sunday DATEPART(weekday,...) = 6 (6= Saturday) or 7 (7=Sunday). And if that's the case i ADD an extra 1 or 2 days

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InDate DATE = '2014-07-17'
DECLARE @number_of_numbers INT = 100000;
DECLARE @MaxBusDays INT = 24
```

This part just sets up the date, the max size of the numbers table and how many business days I want to add

```
;WITH
    a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
    c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
    d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
    e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
    f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
    numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(@number_of_numbers)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
)
```

This section above just sets up a numbers table of 100000 numbers for getting dates.

```
 SELECT
    @InDate StartDate,
    DATENAME(DW, @InDate) StartName, 
    @MaxBusDays DaysToAdd,
    d.* 
 FROM
 (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(DAY, +number, @InDate) CheckDate, 
        DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(DAY, +number, @InDate)) CheckName, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY, +number, @InDate)) MaxRow
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE DATENAME(DW, DATEADD(DAY, +number, @InDate)) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
) d
WHERE d.MaxRow = @MaxBusDays
```

I join against the numbers table and create a range of dates (excluding weekends) and then I just grab the date that is the number of business days I wanted to add. If you use <= it will return an array of all the business days up to that number as well.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BusDaysDateAdd] 
(
   @FromDate datetime,
   @DaysToAdd int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Result datetime

   SET @Result = 
    DATEADD(day, 
        @DaysToAdd + 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) = 2 AND @DaysToAdd > 4 THEN 2 --Mon
            WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) = 3 AND @DaysToAdd > 3 THEN 2 --Tue
            WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) = 4 AND @DaysToAdd > 2 THEN 2 --Wed
            WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) = 5 AND @DaysToAdd > 1 THEN 2 --Thu
            WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) = 6 AND @DaysToAdd > 0 THEN 2 --Fri
            WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) = 7 THEN 2 --Sat
            WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @FromDate) = 1 THEN 1 --Sun
            ELSE 0 
        END, 
    @FromDate)

   RETURN @Result
END
```

It's not multicultural, but it works for skipping weekends instead of just adding extra days if you happen to land on a weekend day.